# want the child element to get parents height

Tags: sencha-touch, internet-explorer-10

I want the child container to take the size of the parent container. As you can see in the picture I want the element circled in red i.e. dataview-container to take the height of element circled in black i.e. scroll-container[image]

The code works fine in google chrome but its the IE 10 that gives the issue. So what do I have to change in the css to make this work. I am using sencha touch and trying in IE 10

In the second image the area in the black box is the one i want to get rid of!![image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need to be able to see code to help you, and preferably some way to run it, such as the URL of your page or a demo on jsfiddle.

Comment: @DavidStorey I will post a jsfiddle link soon, thanks..